# Javascript Prototype question, how do I call a function without this inside a prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
    let Person = function (name, age) {
         this.name = name;
         this.age = age;
      };
      
      Person.prototype.testProto = function ()  {
        console.log(this.name + " == " + this.age);
      
        let xx = function() {
           console.log("in xx");
        }
      };
      
      let person = new Person("Jake",49);
      person.testProto();
```

This will work if I change the "let xx" with "this.xx"
and call it with person.xx();

But not using "this", how is it possible to call it, when person.testProto.xx() won't work?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? From where do you want the log to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return xx variable from function inside.

This will call both testProto Function and also xx function without using `this`.

```js
let Person = function(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
};

Person.prototype.testProto = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " == " + this.age);

  let xx = function() {
    console.log("in xx");
  }
  return xx;
};

let person = new Person("Jake", 49);
person.testProto()();
```